# SQL Server : export specific records to xml file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have created a stored procedure to export specific record from a table to an XML file. The procedure is working properly, but the problem is when trying to execute the procedure it shows the results below :

Execution code :

```
EXEC dbo.SF_ExportXML @myTable = N'Employee', -- nvarchar(255) 
                  @Id = 63,        -- int
                  @myFile = N'D:\Test1.xml'   -- nvarchar(255)
```

Result :

```
NULL
Starting copy...
```

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 102
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Employee'.
>
> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column level collations
>
> NULL
>   BCP copy out failed
>   NULL

The stored procedure is :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SF_ExportXML]
    @myTable NVARCHAR(255),
    @Id INT,
    @myFile NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(255)

    SELECT @cmd = N'bcp "select * from "' + @myTable + '" where Id = "'  + Cast(@Id AS NVARCHAR) + '" Employee for xml auto, root(''rows''), elements" ' +
'queryout "' + @myFile + '" -S .\sqlexpress -T -w -r -t';

    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
END
```

Comment: I think You SP run in **server instance** and path `D:\Test1.xml` not exists in your server

Comment: The SP is working properly without where clause.

Comment: Certainly your SP is work but when you install SP in instance in other computer .The system only knows its paths, not the paths on your computer

Comment: in this case i am using variables in SP to avoid this problem then i will assign it in c# project

Comment: i will show you the result of SP execution when skipping where clause

Comment: give me `Anydesk` in `rezayousefi88@gmail.com`

Comment: Have you tried removing `Employee` from the bcp query string? It would currently concatenate to: `select * from "Employee" where Id = "63" Employee for xml auto, root('rows'), elements`. It might work better as `SELECT @cmd = N'bcp "select * from ' + quotename(@myTable) + ' where Id = ' + cast(@Id AS nvarchar) + ' for xml auto, root(''rows''), elements" ' +
'queryout "' + @myFile + '" -S .\sqlexpress -T -w -r -t';`

Comment: sorry for being late, i have sent the identified number via email